# Update DIV element on the page while looping an object

Tags: javascript

I have a function which loops through an object with many elements using a **for** loop. While looping through each element it connects to the server and sends some data through ajax, waits for response and then goes to the next element in the object. If the object has many elements it can take up to 2 or more minutes before the looping has finished. I would like to visually show on the page how many elements are left before the looping has finished.

The problem is that the screen freezes while looping. Is there a way to update a DIV element on the page while looping through the object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a;//let's assume this is your array
...
...
for(var i =0;i<N;i++)
{
 (function(a,b){setTimeout(f(a,b),0);})(i,a[i]);
}
...
...

function f(current, element)
{
 //call your server api here
 //send data to a div using value of current 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `setInterval()` would help there. It is not actually a loop, but a timer, which lets some function execute periodically.

```
var i = 0; // our index

var myTimer = setInterval(function(){
    //do anything there
    i++;
    if(i>anyMaxValueYouWant){
        clearInterval(myTimer); // break this "loop"
    }
},10)
 ^^^^
interval between the calls of the above function, in milliseconds
```